# How to Import C# DLL into MQL5 script

Tags: c#, mql5

I want to import following C# code which works fine as a dll into MQL5. would you please help me how to do the binding? (I am using Visual Studio 2015).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Keygen
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form2());
        }
    }
}
```

The MQL5 code is:

```
#property strict

#import "Keygen.dll"
void Program();
#import
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnStart()
  {
//---
   Program();
  }
//+--

----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

after compiling in mql5 I get following the error:

```
Cannot find 'Program' in 'Keygen.dll'
unresolved import function call
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with c#. you're just trying to import a dll. Maybe remove the C# tag?

Comment: I know that there are some codes to be added into both c# and mql5 codes to do this binding. so c# tag is necessary.

Comment: Have your considered the [official documentation](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/249)? (BTW this is the first link in Google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by putting the 64bit dll file in "Libraries" folder of MT5 Terminal and changing the MQL code like this.

```
#import "Keygen.dll"
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnStart()
  {
 Program::Main();
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And finally I figured it out. Assembly name, default namespace in project property and namespace name must be the same! Then everything will work as it should.